# RE: Office 365 Home; 5TB; One User instead of spread across 5 @ 1TB Each - How?

Tags: onedrive

> I have been an Office 365 (1 user) subscriber for a while now and am
>   very happy with the service except for one issue, my cloud storage
>   needs have surpassed 1TB.  I use OneDrive faithfully and love it but
>   any day now I am going to over my 1TB of storage.
>
> I looked all over for ways to upgrade my OneDrive storage to 5TB (the
>   size of my drive) so I could no longer worry about running out of
>   space. I could find no way to purchase the extra space. I did,
>   however, notice if I upgraded my 365 Home to the 5-user subscription
>   each user got 1TB of storage for a maximum of 5TB. Exactly what I
>   needed.
>
> My problem is now that I upgraded I can see how to invite other users
>   and give them each 1TB but I don't actually have other users. I just
>   want my OneDrive to hold 5TB.  How do I give myself the entire 5TB? I
>   simply don't nee four more accounts at 1TB each.
>
> If not, is there another way for me to upgrade to 5TB of OneDrive
>   storage?  I truly don't want to have to subscribe to another Cloud
>   Storage service just to get 5TB and am willing to pay a little extra
>   for the space. Perhaps my upgrading to this plan wasn't the way to get
>   the 5TB I need.
>
> I truly just want Office 365 with a 5TB OneDrive. If I need to swap to
>   business plan I will but they all seem to offer 1TB per user also.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odstorage-odsubs/how-to-give-one-office-365-home-user-all-5tb-of/d2e4883d-2181-4c62-ab5a-64f6c16f2961

This question has already been asked also on answers.microsoft.com, but didn't receive any answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 4 more fictional users to your subscription,
where each can go up to 1 TB.
You will need 4 more email addresses to do that.
You will next need to split your files between the user accounts,
because there is no other solution with Home subscription.

Or you may also opt for [OneDrive for Business Plan 2](https://products.office.com/en/onedrive-for-business/compare-onedrive-for-business-plans) for $10/month,
where one user may go up to 5 TB.
Or you might opt for the competition, such as Amazon Cloud Drive.

As there are various providers that will give you 1TB of free cloud space,
you could very thriftily sign up for multiple such services, then use
a product such as [**odrive**](https://www.odrive.com/) to aggregate all your accounts into one system
with one password and one application.
With such a solution, I would suggest being sure of your backups,
because you will be more exposed to provider problems.

For more information about odrive :

- [Odrive Review](http://www.cloudstorage101.com/odrive-review/)
- [Odrive : Differences in sync capabilities between Free and Premium](https://forum.odrive.com/t/what-is-free-vs-paid-premium/961/4)

Comment: Worth pointing out that.  To get a 5TB user you have to pay for multiple users (5+) it seems.

Comment: "5 TB of cloud storage per user for subscriptions with at least five users" but $50 a month for 25TB isn't that bad of a deal.  If I am reading that right.

Comment: Microsoft [says this](https://products.office.com/en/office-365-home) for Office 365 Home : "Get 1 TB of OneDrive cloud storage **each for up to 5 users**" for 7,99 $ per month.

Comment: Talking about the Business Plan 2

Comment: @Ramhound: Right.

Comment: Not a big deal. Using Google Drive 30TB + CrashPlan + Backblaze + 120TB-->60TB NAS + 2 x 10TB Off-Site/On-Site Local Encrypted Backup HDDs, too. Just wanted to know! OneDrive & Dropbox are now out of the question for serious storage as it seems. Besides, I realized, Filemail and such services, are best for temporary/temp storage (instead of uploading to the cloud a 400gb file to share to your buddy overseas)